# Programmatically adding views to Vertical Stack View breaks constraints of vertical stack view

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uistackview

So I have a vertical stack view in a simple layout. When I add a view through Interface Builder I see the view in the stack view no issues.

[image: Just adding a "Blue" view to UIStackView]

When I then add views programmatically to the UIStackView it breaks the constraints and the added views appear at the top of the window. I'm confused as to why it would break the constraints of the stack view.

```
 func buildCats(theJson:JSON){
     //self.verticalStack.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    print(theJson)
    if let infos = self.swiftyJsonvar["info"].array{
        for info in infos{
            guard let v = UINib(nibName: "ticketOrderView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView else { return }
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.verticalStack.addArrangedSubview(v)

        }
    }
}
```

[image: As you can see the added view show up WAY Outside of the vertical stack view..]

Comment: I think it's probably because you are disabling autolayout for the views with this line: `v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. So although the stack view has auto layout, the new views don't

Comment: I have no autolayout on the views I put in through IB. It is just taken care of by the stackview.
I removed that line and also tried setting it to TRUE and get the same behavior each time.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you dont use a tableview for that? You could just design a tablecell for that with its own constraints

Comment: I haven't worked with a stack view programmatically, but I'm pretty sure the added views will need layout constraints (Top, Bottom, Leading & Trailing)

Answer (score 0):

<s>The added subviews need constraints, as they have no intrinsic size. Try:</s>

v.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30).isActive = true
v.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 200).isActive = true

<s>Hmmm.... I'm doubting this now... I suspect the issue may be related to adding the views on a background thread. Maybe run the loop on the main thread?</s>

Edit 2: Ah... the problem I'm betting now is related to what you're doing with the view / subviews inside your "ticketOrderView"

For an example, see: https://github.com/DonMag/ScratchPad